# load data from database to text box

Tags: javascript, php

I have a mysql database table called 'employees'
It has 3 columns named 'id', 'name' and 'salary'
I have html/php web page with text boxes called id and name.
I want to load 'id' and 'name' of the employee who has the maximum salary,  from database to these text boxes.

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far and anything you have tried, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
//Defining constants for database connection best to store in seperate file and include that file
    const DB_HOST = 'SERVER';
        const DB_USER = 'USER';
        const DB_PASS = 'PASSWORD';
        const DB_NAME = 'php_mysql_login_system';
    //Connecting to the database -- best use pdo
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        # check connection
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
            exit();
        }


        $sql = " SELECT * from `employees` "; // query data from databse -- alhough I suggest you use pdo

        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        //Looping through each  results

        foreach ($result as  $value) {

            // Store the employess salary and name in an array say employee['name'=>salaray] -- name as key and salary as value
        }

        $maximumSalary = max(//array of the employee i.e the one you have made above employee[]);

        //after getting the maximum value use array_keys(array,value) to get the employee name

        $employeeName = array_keys($employee,$maximumSalary);

    }
    ?>
```

A sample code to get you started hope this helps you although this code might not be following best practise it is for you to get started with at least something as I think you are having trouble getting started.